# How to use a data identifier on an array of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there I'm currently building a slider and I got pretty much all nailed down except one last thing.

My bullet points are identifying what image you are currently looking at and can also be used for navigation as illustrated here (2 sliders since this is where im running into issues):

http://puu.sh/hAYp5/15477cd325.png

For the actual dots I've been able to use this code:

```
$(this.dots).click(function() {
  var selected = $(this).data("img");
  sliderEle.goTo(selected);
  $(dots).removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active")
})
```

The prev and next buttons however I'm having an issue figuring out, this is what I currently got and it affects both sliders as it is none specific to the individual slider like I want it to be:

```
goTo: function(index) {
if (index < 0)
  return;

// move <ul> left
this.ul.style.left = '-' + (100 * index) + '%';

this.currentIndex = index
},

goToPrev: function() {
 this.goTo(this.currentIndex - 1)
 $(this.dots).removeClass("active");
 $('.slider-dot[data-img="'+this.currentIndex+'"]').addClass("active");
},

goToNext: function() {
 if(this.currentIndex + 1 > this.li.length - 1) {
  this.goTo(0)
 }else {
  this.goTo(this.currentIndex + 1)
 }
 $(this.dots).removeClass("active");
 $('.slider-dot[data-img="'+this.currentIndex+'"]').addClass("active")
}
```

How do I change this line:

```
$('.slider-dot[data-img="'+this.currentIndex+'"]').addClass("active")
```

To work with something like this:

```
$(this.dots)
```

So it's targeted on the individual slider rather than all sliders.

Full js source: http://pastebin.com/NaDw0jib

Comment: can u add code to JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using .filter from jquery

```
var currentDot = $(this.dots).filter('[data-img="'+this.currentIndex+'"]');
$(currentDot).addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

add a function to your prototype

```
getNav: function(index) {
    return  $(this.nav).filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('img') === index;
    });
});
```

ten use it like this:

```
this.getNav(3).addClass('active');
```

As an aside, I'd probably either expand the initialize method to actually create the DOM representation, or failing that, at least use classes rather than hard coding to children[i] references. It'll save you a headache later.